# try-finally block continue for loop

Tags: java, try-finally

I'm writing a loop that ignored the **Exception** and it works well.

```
    for (; flag; ) {
        try {
            //do something ignore exception.
            Runnable r = queue.pollFirst();
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // ignored.
        }
    }
```

But my question is: If I don't **catch RuntimeException** and force **continue** loop in **finally** block, what will happen to the Exception and returned value?

Example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(i);

            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            //what will happen to the exception if continue loop?
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: continue results in the exception or return value being discarded.  You can easily tests this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: although I agree with you that it is not a great question, just trying something does not guarantee that the observed behavior is what happens in all cases

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know exceptions are ignored. Will it cause some problem? memory leak or stack overflow or something.

Comment: @Oebele correct, but you might start with the assumption that it is, show you have tried it for yourself and ask if this is guaranteed behaviour or not. +1

Comment: @lymoge you do realize that it is a horrible idea to just catch all exceptions and continue executing your program? If there is an exception you did not expect, you can't know whether the rest of your program executes correctly.

Comment: @lymoge The GC still works correctly and the stack doesn't get deeper when you do this.

Comment: @Oebele: I understand that I should not ignore RuntimeException. that code is an example, next one is the point.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes! That's my question! continue inside finally is very strange to me.

Comment: @lymoge agreed, it's a strange/confusing thing to do, like using `break;` or `return;` there. Not all valid code makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

They will be `ignored` as the `finally` block has the `final` word.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime Exception will be ignored because there is no catch block to access/use (e.g. for logging purpose) thrown object of java.lang.RuntimeException. finally block does not have any access to Exception object thrown by try block. Its better to have catch block to get more information.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would want to catch a RuntimeException because by the time you even try catching it, it's too late therefore your continue will never hit.