# continue in finally causes java.lang.VerifyError: "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

Tags: java, verifyerror

Doing some code-puzzles in Java, I came up with the following code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int result = bar();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int bar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                return i;
            } finally {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

It compiles with one warning:

> finally block does not complete normally

During runtime, I get the following error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting
>   a stackmap frame at branch target 11 Exception Details:   Location:
>       Foo.bar()I @11: if_icmplt   Reason:
>       Expected stackmap frame at this location.   Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 033b a700 0684 0001 1a10 64a1 0000 02ac
>       0x0000010:                                           Stackmap Table:
>       append_frame(@5,Integer)
>       same_frame(@8)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)

I would say that this should not happen, right?
What would be the "correct" behavior based on the Java specification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [try-finally block continue for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007725/try-finally-block-continue-for-loop)

Comment: @vinS: I don't see the other question mentioning a VerifyError. And the highest voted answer just states "They will be ignored as the finally block has the final word." - that definitely does not happen here. So no, I wouldn't call it a duplicate.